# how do i use date mutators or carbon in sql queries

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

If i have a sql query returning from  DB::Select how can i return Carbon objects for my created_at attributes?

i would like to be able to do something like:

```
$result = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT X,Y,Z,tabletwo.created_at FROM tableone LEFT JOIN tabletwo ON tableone.X = tabletwo.foreignX"));

   foreach($result as $row)
   {

      $row->created_at->timezone(Auth::user()->timezone);

   }
```

I have already tried adding the fields into the getDates method on my models but it doesn't make a different- i assume since its a custom sql query and not returning an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DB::select` returns array of `stdObjects`, not Eloquent `Models`, so you can't use Eloquent features.

Assuming `created_at` is MySQL timestamp/date field, you can do this:

```
$timestamp = new Carbon\Carbon($row->created_at);
$timestamp->timezone(Auth::user()->timezone);
```

Comment: This is what i ended up doing but more inline for the view. {{Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',$token->redeemed_at)->timezone(Auth::user()->timezone)}}